# Redirect DNS server IPs on Unifi UDM-Pro using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, unifi

I'm using a Unifi UDM Pro as a gateway for 2 VLANs:

- Main LAN (interface: `br0`, subnet: `192.168.1.1/24`)
- IoT Devices VLAN (interface: `br3`, subnet: `192.168.3.1/24`)

Each has its own local DNS (Adguard Home) server (`192.168.1.52` and `192.168.3.52` respectively). For each subnet, I want to prevent clients from bypassing the local DNS server assigned via DHCP. In order to do this, I SSH into the UDM Pro and execute these commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s 192.168.1.52 ! -d 192.168.1.52 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.52
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s 192.168.1.52 ! -d 192.168.1.52 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.52

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br3 ! -s 192.168.3.52 ! -d 192.168.3.52 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.52
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br3 ! -s 192.168.3.52 ! -d 192.168.3.52 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.52

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
```

I test these using two main methods: `dig` and via WLAN devices (e.g. iPad):

Using the `dig` method, I test first a direct DNS query and then one to a Google DNS server. I run both commands on the physical host for my DNS server (which is a member of every VLAN via the Debian `vlan` package):

1. `dig linux.org '@192.168.3.52' -b '192.168.3.52'`
2. `dig linux.org '@8.8.8.8' -b '192.168.3.52'`

The first command above works fine. The second one gives me a time out. I expect the second one to still work, except to be routed through `192.168.3.52`.

If I run the same `dig` commands above but on the main LAN, both work fine and I can see both queries on my local DNS server.

I'm not sure why VLAN 3 doesn't work in the redirect case, but my main LAN does. Can someone help me understand why this isn't working and show me a working solution?

Comment: If you run these command from `.52` it would be excluded from the redirection.
Check and verify that the rules get hit (iptables counters are helpful) then use tcpdump to see which traffic goes where, My guess is on the MASQUERADE rule that might not work, or causing issues, but tcpdump will tell you if that is the case.

Comment: I thought about running from .52 causing issues, but I'd expect `8.8.8.8` to still give me a response back, just not redirect through my local DNS server. But the request times out completely. Also FWIW, testing through an iPad on that VLAN, I'm still seeing the timeout. I'm not an expert at iptables, tcpdump. Can you provide some example commands to run and where to run them? Thank you!